# How to pass a password to a new EC2 instance created via a Jenkins Pipeline with Terraform?

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu, amazon-ec2

I am currently creating a pipeline. The pipeline is triggered by a GitHook from GitHub to Jenkins. Jenkins then uses Terraform to create an EC2 Instance, which through a script installs the necessary python libraries and runs the python program. That python program is a web-scraper. Once a value changes it sends an email. Locally the password is held in the OS so it works. However once uploaded to the EC2 instance it needs the password and causes an error.

How can I securely pass the password to the EC2 instance?

I have added a variable to /etc/profile /.zshrc

however none seem to work?